# How to manage a dynamic menu with separators?

Tags: c#, menuitem, separator

I have to develop a simple menu on a Form, like :

- File

  - Option A
  - Option B
  - -------- (separator 1)
  - Option C
  - Option D
  - -------- (separator 2)
  - Option E

Each entry is stored in an DB and is visible or not, depending on connected user rights

For example, User "J.Doe" will not see the options C and D

My question is : how to do, to dynamically avoid that the menu shows the 2 separators, since, obviously, only one is required betwen Option B and E?

Comment: what effort have you done to attempt to solve the problem?

Comment: I tried to store in a bool, when I insert a separator.
Then, if the next menuitem is also a separator, so I don't insert it. 
But it's confused, and I asking me if there's not a correct or easiest way to do that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simply add the separator if the three following conditions are met:

1. There is at least one menu item already present.
2. The previous menu item is not a separator.
3. There is at least one more menu item to add after the current one.

That shouldn't be too hard. Try writing code following this specification and if you run into trouble come here and ask again about more specific coding issues.

*UPDATE*: Seeing the solutions proposed here, which are all tailored to your specific question, I'll just go ahead and show you how I'd solve the general problem in a way that works for *any* menu configuration:

```
static void DynamicallySetMenuItems(MenuItem menu, UserRole role)
{
    var menuItems = GetMenuItems(role);
    var previous = menuItems.FirstOrDefault();

    if (previous == null)
        return;

    if (!IsSeparator(previous))
    {    
        menu.MenuItems.Add(previous);
    }

    foreach (var current in menuItems.Skip(1))
    {
        if (!IsSeparator(current) ||
            !IsSeparator(previous))
        {
            menu.MenuItems.Add(previous);
        }

        previous = current;
    }        

    if (IsSeparator(previous))
    {
        menu.MenuItems.Remove(previous);
    }
}

static bool IsSeparator(MenuItem menu)
    => menu.Text == "-";
```

Comment: @Downvoter No, no, no, thats not nice, at least explain why the downvote ;)

Answer (score -2):

You just build the menu on the fly, as such:

```
            var myMenu = new ContextMenuStrip(); // works also with tool strip menus, main menu, etc...
            int m = 0;
            if( /* has option A */ )
            {
             myMenu.Items.Add("Option A");
             myMenu.Items[m++].Click += OptionA_Click;
            }
            if( /* has option B */ )
            {
             myMenu.Items.Add("Option B");
             myMenu.Items[m++].Click += OptionB_Click;
            }
            if( /* has option C or D */ )
            {
             myMenu.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());
             m++;
            }
            if( /* has option C */ )
            {
             myMenu.Items.Add("Option C");
             myMenu.Items[m++].Click += OptionC_Click;
            }
            if( /* has option D */ )
            {
             myMenu.Items.Add("Option D");
             myMenu.Items[m++].Click += OptionD_Click;
            }
            if( /* has option E */ )
            {
             myMenu.Items.Add(new ToolStripSeparator());
             myMenu.Items.Add("Option E");
             myMenu.Items[++m].Click += OptionE_Click;
            }
```